# How to return a method value from Optional ifPresentOrElse

Tags: java

I have a compile error because findByUserIdAndVoteDate returns void ( not VoteResponseDTO ), voteRepository.save() - returns the value I need, how can I get it?

```
    public VoteResponseDTO addVote(User user, VoteCreationDTO voteCreationDTO) {  
   VoteResponseDTO createdVote = voteRepository.findByUserIdAndVoteDate(user.getId(), LocalDate.now(clock))
                .ifPresentOrElse(oldVote -> {
                            var vote = new Vote(user, restaurant);
                            vote.setId(oldVote.getId());
                            voteRepository.save(vote);
                        },
                        () -> voteRepository.save(new Vote(user, restaurant)));
        }
```

[image]

Comment: looks like you want `.map(oldVote -> /*first-lambda-body*/).orElseGet(() -> /*second-lambda-body*/)`, rather than `ifPresentOrElse` which returns void

Comment: If VoteResponseDTO a member of a frame work please provide an url for it. If it a usergenerated item please add class source code to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Michael, it works.

```
VoteResponseDTO voteResponse = toVoteResponseDTO(voteRepository.findByUserIdAndVoteDate(user.getId(), LocalDate.now(clock))
                .map(oldVote -> {
                    var vote = new Vote(user, restaurant);
                    vote.setId(oldVote.getId());
                    return voteRepository.save(vote);
                }).orElseGet(
                        () -> voteRepository.save(new Vote(user, restaurant))));
```